# Parametric inequality

Tags: inequality

$k$ is a non negative real parameter.
I have to study for which real $x$, $x^4+4-k^2$ is greater than zero and for which is $\leq 0$.

My prof says about the solutions that in the first case I have the ``big'' $x$ and $k<2$; in the latter, I have the little ones
and $k\geq2$.

My question is: shouldn't I have solutions only for $k>2$?
And how can I obtain these solutions?

Comment: I suppose that it is $k<2$ and $k \ge 2$, not $h$. Right?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider

$$f(x)=x^4+4$$

and then study the conditions for

$$f(x)=x^4+4\ge h= k^2$$

$$f(x)=x^4+4\le h= k^2$$

with $h=k^2 \ge 0$.

Notably since $f(x)\ge 4$

- for $0<h\le4\implies f(x)\ge h \quad \forall x$
- for $h>4\\\implies f(x)\ge h \quad \forall x\in (-\infty,-\sqrt[4] h]\cup [\sqrt[4]h,+\infty)\\\implies f(x)\le h \quad \forall x\in [-\sqrt[4] h,\sqrt[4] h]$

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer

Answer (score 0):

write your inequality in the form
$$x^4\geq k^2-4$$
if $$k\le 2$$ then our inequality is fulffiled.
For $$k\geq 2$$ we get $$|x|\geq \sqrt[4]{k^2-4}$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you!